# looking for an SSH client that allows xwindows

Tags: terminal, catalina, ssh, x11

I've recently started using macOS. I am looking for an SSH client that allows xwindow tunneling through SSH. As suggested, I've installed Xquartz via brew but whenever I try opening an xwindow based app like gvim or Firefox, I get an error like this:

`E233: cannot open display`

I'm logging into the host like this:
`ssh -X user@domain` . I've also tried replacing the `-X` with `-Y` but it makes no difference at all. I've tried this with native terminal, iterm2 and termius. The latter two are great but they lack this very important feature that allows me to open things like Firefox and gvim directly from the terminal. Using putty is out of the question as it seems that it is no longer supported.

Perhaps I am doing it wrong. Looking for tips/advice etc

Comment: The standard ssh in macOS supports X11. Can you add details about what exactly you tried and how it failed?

Comment: Also, have you installed Xquartz?

Comment: @nohillside I did now but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: Is Xquartz running? Did you enable X11 in the ssh/sshd config (there are Q&A about this on AD and on other sites)? Is DISPLAY set (best to try from xterm first)?

Comment: Basically from a running xterm, you should be able to do `ssh -X remotehost` and then, once logged in, run `firefox` to launch a remote Firefox which uses your Mac to display the UI.

Comment: What does the remote think $DISPLAY is set to when you log into it via SSH?

Comment: @nohillside After installing Xquartz, I can now use graphical apps. I had to restart and start it manually first. I now have configured for it to start at login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X11 isn't available in macOS by default but can be installed via [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/). Once installed, you can

- open Xterm and run `ssh -X remotehost` from there
- open Xterm, run `echo $DISPLAY`, set the variable to the same value in Terminal and run `ssh -X remotehost` from Terminal